# JS - Is there any way to check if the value is already present in csv or not

Tags: javascript, csv, duplicates

I am extracting data from a website but the listings can be duplicate in any other region. so, I would like to know how can I check the value extracted if it is already present in the CSV or not, if yes, the loop should break else continue.

Since the CSV is going to be big so, i need the fastest way to check the data.

Please, tell me a solution based on javascript. No jquery or Java or any other customized js.

Comment: Do you have an id to identify each line in your csv? Can you give an example of your CSV?

Comment: Here is the sample link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S7n5NhHmhsZ2_TpQCy1NQ0SbZaXLGGejqEu-JC-MaG4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to match with column k (Realtor Link)

Comment: What module are you using for parsing CSV? (Yes, you need a CSV parser in order to correctly parse CSV. No, you can't just split lines on commas.)

Comment: @JordanRunning Sorry could you explain about module

Comment: @Dimitri I have shared the link of csv, I want to match the value with column k (Realtor Link)

Comment: "Module" as in "library" or "somebody else's code." You don't want to write your own CSV parser, and [lots of people have already done the work for you](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv%20parser&page=1&ranking=optimal).

Comment: @JordanRunning i can't use any library since imacros only accepts the raw javascript

Comment: Where does the CSV data come from? Can you preprocess it locally?

Comment: @JordanRunning I scrape the data using iMacros, i need to put some functionalities so that i can get a column into an array and check the value if it is present in csv or not.